# UPDATED!: Time Converter - Assigned functions do not work

Tags: python, function, user-interface, tkinter

*I've built a time conversion widget, the problems I am facing is with the functions I am assigning to specific variables. I would like to work so that when a number is entered in one EntryBox, the other update immediately.*

*quick outline, with the functions in the code below I am trying to attain the value entered in one Entry, and then convert that value twice, to produce two more values which are then assigned to the relevant variable.*

EDIT: I have managed to get one of the functions working, part in thanks to Sujay for point out the *args error. I have now updated the code below to reflect where I am now. The functions appear to work as desire, except for the instance where only entering a value on the HOUR Entry delivers a value in the other two Entries. Entering a value in the Second or Minute Entry yields nothing.

Again any help or guidance is appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import*

#Global Variables 
root = Tk()

Second = DoubleVar()
Minute = DoubleVar()
Hour = DoubleVar()

#GUI 
class GUI:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.self = self
        self.master = master
        master.title('Time Converter')
        master.geometry('+600+300')
        master.label1 = Label(root, text = 'Second').grid(column=0, row=0)
        master.entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=Second).grid(pady=5, padx=20, column=0, row=1)
        master.label2 = Label(root, text= ' Minute').grid(column=1, row=0)
        master.entry2 = Entry(root, textvariable=Minute).grid(pady=5, padx=20, column=1, row=1)
        master.label3 = Label(root, text= ' Hour').grid(column=2, row=0)
        master.entry3 = Entry(root, textvariable=Hour).grid(pady=5, padx=20, column=2, row=1)
    
    UpdateInProgress = False


#Conversion Functions
def SecondInput(*args):
    GUI.UpdateInProgress
    if GUI.UpdateInProgress: return
    try:
        Second.get()
    except ValueError:
        return
    NewMinute = (Second.get()/60)
    NewHour = (Second.get()/3600)
    GUI.UpdateInProgress = True
    Minute.set(NewMinute)
    Hour.set(NewHour)
    GUI.UpdateInProgress = False

def MinuteInput(*args):
    GUI.UpdateInProgress
    if GUI.UpdateInProgress: return
    try:
        Minute.get()
    except ValueError:
        return
    NewSecond = (Minute.get()*60)
    NewHour = (Minute.get()*0.01667)
    GUI.UpdateInProgress = True
    Second.set(NewSecond)
    Hour.set(NewHour)
    GUI.UpdateInProgress = False

def HourInput(*args):
    GUI.UpdateInProgress
    if GUI.UpdateInProgress: return
    try:
        Hour.get()
    except ValueError:
        return
    NewMinute = (Hour.get()*60)
    NewSecond = (Hour.get()*3600)
    GUI.UpdateInProgress = True
    Minute.set(NewMinute)
    Second.set(NewSecond)
    GUI.UpdateInProgress = False

#Assigning functions to variables
Second.trace("w",MinuteInput)
Minute.trace("w",SecondInput)
Hour.trace("w",HourInput)

#Mainloop
def main():
    GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: ```MinuteInput(*args)``` can solve it.

Comment: Thank, that got me a little futher however no I am being thrown back this error. 

return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\ab5302\Desktop\Untitled-1.py", line 27, in SecondInput
    if Second >= 0.1:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'DoubleVar' and 'float'

Comment: Ya, I am actually working on improving your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this issue

Assigned the functions to the wrong variables.

*sighs*

Thanks to Sujay for commenting, here's where the issue was:

```
Second.trace("w",MinuteInput)
Minute.trace("w",SecondInput)
Hour.trace("w",HourInput)
```

should have been

```
Second.trace("w",SecondInput)
Minute.trace("w",MinuteInput)
Hour.trace("w",HourInput)
```